# Countable base for the one point compactification topology on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

I see similar results on this site, but I am unable to find the explicit base,  $$\{B(x,1/n):x\in \mathbb{C}, x=a+ib,a,b\in \mathbb{Q},n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}^c$$.

Will this work?

Comment: $\{0\}^c$ is not enough. Take all $\{z:|z|>n\}$ too (they provide a base at the infinite point).

Comment: Can you explain why

Comment: I could but the explanation should be obvious if you review the definition of the topology on the one point compactification of $\Bbb C$, and in particular how one defines neighborhoods at the $\infty$ point.

Comment: You need a countable decreasing family for the local base at $\infty$, and @Mirko's work fine.

Comment: Can you give a counter example to say my collection is not enough

Comment: @MadhanKumar A counterexample is already contained in my first comment. Take any $n\ge1$. E.g. Take $n=5$. Then $\{z:|z|>5\}$ (including the point $\infty$) is an open set, a neighborhood of $\infty$, and there is no set in your proposed base that contains $\infty$ and is contained in $\{z:|z|>5\}$. (If that is not enough, now take $n=7$, and if that is not enough take $n=100$,... :)